# How to make a shader fade to a color?

Tags: c++, shader, sfml

This is the current shader I am using. It fades the object by slowly reducing the opacity. I want to fade to purple. How can this be done?

shader.frag:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float opacity;

void main()
{
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    gl_FragColor = pixel * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);
}
```

shader.vert:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

application of shader in main function:

```
sf::Shader shader;
if (!shader.loadFromFile("shader.vert", "shader.frag"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

float opacity = 1.0; //transparency of shader
shader.setParameter("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture); //shader.vert
shader.setParameter("opacity", opacity);                    //shader.frag
```

////////////////////////////

```
//Delete Text Display
    counter1 = 0;
    for (iter8 = textDisplayArray.begin(); iter8 != textDisplayArray.end(); iter8++)
    {
        if (textDisplayArray[counter1].destroy == true)
        {
            //shader
            opacity -= 0.1;         
            if (opacity <= 0)
            {
                textDisplayArray.erase(iter8);
                opacity = 1;
            }
            shader.setParameter("opacity", opacity);
        }
```

Comment: Thx for responding so quickly, I plugged the code in and it does half of what I want it to do: It does fade to purple, but it appears as a rectangle that obscures the text. Is there a way to make the text and/or a sprite fade to a purple outline of the sprite/text?

Answer (score 5):

The RGB value for purple is `vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 )` (maximum red, minimal green and maximum blue). You have to interpolate between your frgment color and the color value of purpel, similar as you do it with `opacity`. Use `mix` for this. `mix(x, y, a)` performs a linear interpolation between `x` and `y` using `a` to weight between them. The return value is computed as *x×(1−a)+y×ax×(1−a)+y×a*.

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float opacity;
uniform float purpleFac;

void main()
{
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    vec3 mixedCol = mix( vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ), pixel.rgb, purpleFac );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( mixedCol , opacity );
}
```

Note you have to set uniform `purpleFac` similar as you do it with `opacity`. `purpleFac` shoud be in range [0.0, 1.0]. If `purpleFac` is `1.0` your fragment is colord purple and if it is `0.0` your fragment colol is the color of the texture only.