# Text and shaders

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

Using SFML 2.4, I want to draw a text on the screen and apply effects on it with a fragment shader. But when I try it, the text is drawn with squares instead of characters

Fragment shader :

```
void main() { gl_FragColor= vec4(1,0,0,1); }
```

SFML text code :

```
sf::Text t;
t.setFont(myFont);
t.setCharacterSize(10);
t.setColor(sf::Color::White);
t.setString("this is a test");

//myWindow.draw(t); // This displays a white "this is a test"
//myWindow.draw(t, myShader); // This displays red squares instead of characters
```

I expected my shader to display that text in red. But instead I get red squares. Each square is the size of the bounding box of the character that's supposed to be there.
Am I missing something obvious here? Or is sf::Text just not intended to be used that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how SFML text rendering works, but I highly suspect it puts the text into a texture. In that case, your fragment shader has to sample the texture to determine the color of a given fragment. Just setting the fragment color to red will do just that: set every rendered fragment to red. Try this:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st) * vec4(1,0,0,1);    
}
```

This will sample the currently bound texture at the texture coordinates passed in from the vertex shader, and tint it red.

Comment: I think you're right. I just stumbled upon this answer on SO that samples the texture:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35217489/5803074

Answer (score 0):

Your shader is setting the entire fragment to be colored red, thus coloring over the text.

Try multiplying the fragment's color instead of setting it, like this:

```
void main() { gl_FragColor *= vec4(1,0,0,1); }
```

Comment: That gives weird results. I still have the red squares, but they're "glitching". On every frame some parts of the squares go black, and it changes every frame.

Comment: @qxz posted a new answer, and I think he's right. The texture needs to be sampled. Check out this SO post for doing that:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35217489/5803074

Comment: Yeah, just multiplying `gl_FragColor` before even assigning anything to it seems like it would probably result in undefined behavior.